# How to set variable arguments in scipy.optimize.curve_fit in Python?

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I am using `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` to do an optimization problem in Python. The `curve_fit` function takes inputs as `curve_fit(f, xdata, ydata, ...)`, in which `f` callable is the model function, `f(x, ...)`. It must take the independent variable as the first argument and the parameters to fit as separate remaining arguments.

However, in my case, the remaining arguments are variable. For example, `f` can be `f = fun(indepent_var, a, b, c, d)`, or `f = fun(indepent_var, a, c, d)`.

The actual arguments of `f` are defined by users when solving the optimization problem. For example, one user might want to use a, b, c, d as the arguments, and another user wants to use a, c, d, and the 3rd user might use b, c. Then, my question is how to set variable arguments in `f` and then users can configurize their own arguments?

```
def func(data, a, b, c, d):
    return a * np.exp(-b * data) + c        

#def func(data, a, c, d):
#    return a * np.exp(-c * x)

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata)

"config_1.ini"
params_to_be_optimized = a, b, c, d

"config_2.ini"
params_to_be_optimized = a, c, d
```

I am trying to do something like this:

```
def func(data, **kwargs):
    a = kwargs['a'] if a in kwargs else 0
    ...
    return ...
    
popt, pcov = curve_fit(lambda(...), xdata, ydata)
```

But I don't know exactly how to solve the problem. I suppose `lambda` function may work, but can anyone give me an example?

Comment: A very example of the function f:
if users define the arguments as a, b, c, then
def f(data, a, b, c):
     return a * data - b - c
but if users define the argument as b, c, d, then
def f(data, b, c, d):
    return data / b + c * d

And so on...

Comment: If you provide a minimal example, you will get more precise help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Look at `*args` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31388319/passing-args-in-scipy-optimize-minimize-objective-function-getting-error-on-nu

Comment: https://pythontips.com/2013/08/04/args-and-kwargs-in-python-explained/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7165877 this shows how to use `scipy.optimize` and also includes setting initial parameter guesses

Answer (score 4):

With the example in the `curve_fit` docs:

```
In [260]: def func(x, a, b, c):
     ...:     return a * np.exp(-b * x) + c
     ...: 
In [261]: xdata = np.linspace(0, 4, 50)
     ...: y = func(xdata, 2.5, 1.3, 0.5)
     ...: np.random.seed(1729)
     ...: y_noise = 0.2 * np.random.normal(size=xdata.size)
     ...: ydata = y + y_noise
```

Without a `p0` parameter the number of fit parameters is determined by introspection, that is, examining the `func` code and attributes

```
p0 : None, scalar, or N-length sequence, optional

Initial guess for the parameters. If None, then the initial values will all be 1 (if the number of parameters for the function can be determined using introspection, otherwise a ValueError is raised).
```

In this case it identifies 3 parameters:

```
In [263]: optimize.curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata)
Out[263]: 
(array([ 2.55423706,  1.35190947,  0.47450618]),
 array([[ 0.0158905 ,  0.00681778, -0.0007614 ],
        [ 0.00681778,  0.02019919,  0.00541905],
        [-0.0007614 ,  0.00541905,  0.00282595]]))
```

I can define a equivalent function using `*args`:

```
In [264]: def f1(x, *args):
     ...:     return func(x, *args)
     ...:
```

But if I try to fit it, I get an error:

```
In [266]: optimize.curve_fit(f1, xdata, ydata)
ValueError: Unable to determine number of fit parameters.
```

But I can specify a `p0`:

```
In [268]: optimize.curve_fit(f1, xdata, ydata, p0=np.ones(3))
Out[268]: 
(array([ 2.55423706,  1.35190947,  0.47450618]),
 ....)
```

If I give other `p0` sizes I get errors as `f1` passes its arguments on to `func`.  I could define `f1` so it was more tolerant of other args numbers, but I might then get `OptimizeWarning`.

Comment: Hi, it seems your question (or answer) is related to mine, but it not actually answering my question.

Answer (score 2):

This may not be a complete answer, but is too long for a comment.
For sure, providing a more concrete example of what you're trying to do would definitely help clarify your question and lead to better answers.

It's not entirely clear to me what the signature of your function is, but it may be that the basic question is how to have the user select which of the function arguments become variables in the fit while having other arguments *not* become variables, either remaining at some fixed value or being used as switches for what functional form to actually use (which seems like what your clarifying comment was trying to say).

In either case, you may find lmfit (https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/) useful.  It has a Model class that supports curve-fitting based on scipy.optimize but separate from (and somewhat higher level than) `curve_fit`.  `lmfit.Model` can turn any "model function" into a Model that can be used to fit to data, and uses inspection to turn the function arguments into Parameters used in the fit.  Any of the Parameters can be variable or fixed (or have bounds or be set by a simple constraint expression), which might be what you're looking for: the user can decide that some of the function arguments would not be fit variables.

Also, if the model function has keyword arguments that don't have numerical defaults, they do not become fit variables, but can be used as optional switches, perhaps controlling the functional form used.   That is, if you have a model function like

```
def func(x, a=1, b=2, c=3, d=0, option=True):
     if option:
         return a * np.exp(-b*x) + c + d*x
     else:
         return a * np.exp(-b*x**2) + c + d*x
```

Then you could create a fitting model and parameters with

```
from lmfit impor Model
mymodel = Model(func)
params = mymodel.make_params(a=100, b=-1, c=0, d=0)
```

and then (for example) fix `d` to be 0:

```
params['d'].value = 0
params['d'].vary = False
```

or apply other starting values, bounds, etc.

To change the value of the `option` argument, you would treat it as another independent variable, passing it to `mymodel.fit()`, or `mymodel.eval()` as a keyword argument, like this:

```
xdata = <array of data>
ydata = <array of data>

result = mymodel.fit(ydata, params, x=xdata, option=False)
print(result.fit_report())
```

That would allow the user to select the options used in the model function.

Hope that points you in the right direction....

**After updates to question:**

In general, supporting `**kws` would be very hard: the user can pass in anything to this dict and how it is used in the function is unknown. Fitting variables have to be floating point numbers, for example.  But, you might also recognize that

```
def func(data, **kwargs):
    a = kwargs['a'] if a in kwargs else 0
    ...
```

can be restated as

```
def func(data, a=0, **kwargs):
    ...
```

and this *is* supported. That would mean you would have to explicitly make function arguments for all quantities that could potentially be variables, but that should not be too hard.  Once that is done, the user can decide which of these are actually varied in a particular fit.

You can definitely use something like

```
def func(x, a=1, b=2, c=3, d=0):
     ...

# read from "config_1.ini"
params_to_be_optimized = 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'

# read from "config_2.ini"
params_to_be_optimized = 'a', 'c', 'd'
```

and something like

```
mymodel = Model(func)
params = mymodel.make_params()   

for parname, param in params.items():
    param.vary = parname in params_to_be_optimized
```

to control which parameters will be optimized and which will be fixed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it seems your approach cannot really fix my problem, because the arguments of the fitting function are variable. I have edited my question again. Could you please help me on it?

Comment: I updated the answer to respond to the updated question.

Comment: Thank you so much. However, I would like to stick on scipy.optimize.curve_fit, due to some requirements. Do you have any ideas how to solve it in curve_fit directly? Thank you.

Comment: @Junyong this sort of use-case was a large part of why we wrote lmfit, and to have Parameter objects that have names and attributes like `vary` instead of plain, floating point variables.  I could be wrong, but I don't think `curve_fit` can handle keyword arguments or multiple independent arguments. It can now handle bounds, but with lists of bounds that are ordered to match the variable list and the positional arguments of the function.  The interface is ugly and screams out for Parameter objects.  Hence, lmfit.

Comment: @M Newville Yes, I have tried different approaches with curve_fit in my codes, and none of them is working. I will definitely try lmfit. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

really, you can only refer to [curve_fit](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) **Signature** ONLY - and in lib's module *minpack.py* is definitely told

> "if 'args' in kwargs: The specification for the model function f does
> not support additional arguments. Refer to the curve_fit docstring for
> acceptable call signatures of f."

- again refering to Signature of the curve_fit function (where input of additional non-optimized parameters is absent) –

the only programming *Trick* you can use:

1. define your arg outside the function & *before* curve_fit function to use it in optimization process inside the objective (for the computer its variable value will be already know) -- # IF variable arg is being defined in the module, where curve_fit & objective functions exist
2. make arg variable Global - # IF variable arg is being defined in another module from where curve_fit & objective functions exist
3. or better import that module as usually & use var from it without need to define it as global

p.s. global vars is not good, though can be used if needed... too large topic for discussion - no sence here

it's just a Trick

It's all just about Code_Design